# $k$-module structures on $\rm End(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $k$ be an abstract field and $V$ a $k$-module. There is an obvious $k$-module structure on $\operatorname{\mathrm{End}}(V)$ by $f:k \times \operatorname{\mathrm{End}}(V) \to \operatorname{\mathrm{End}}(V), (a,\phi)\mapsto a\cdot\phi$  where $(a\cdot \phi)(v)=a\cdot(\phi(v))$.

My question is: is this the only $k$-module structure on $\operatorname{\mathrm{End}}(V)$?

Take $k=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ for instance, we may let $(\pi \cdot \phi)(v)=2\pi\cdot(\phi(v))$, with $(g(\pi) \cdot \phi)(v)=g(2\pi)\cdot(\phi(v))$ for any $g \in k(x)$, the fraction field of the polynomial ring $k[x]$.

Does anything change if we require $k$ to be algebraically closed?

This question arises when given the representation $\rho:A \to \operatorname{\mathrm{End}}(V)$ of an associative algebra $A$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. It seems all the examples I come across are the obvious case. Is this some kind of convention?

Comment: No, you can precompose with any endomorphism of $k$, and those still exist even in the algebraically closed case (and are usually plentiful, at least assuming the axiom of choice). But for most purposes you won't want to; this is the natural $k$-module structure, in a way that can be made precise.